# Getting Dogtail to work with QT on GNOME 2

Tags: automated-testing, gui

My question is in regards to GNOME 2 running on a CENTOS 5 box.

I'm trying to get the [Dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) automation tool to work with my given box for the purpose of testing a QT application. Versions .7 (which is specifically for GNOME 2) and .9 (which didn't specify what version it was supposed to be for) don't appear to have the bridge to get QT's widgets to show up in Dogtail's Sniff functionality.

The QT-AT-SPI (bridge used in later versions) downloads I've seen are all for GNOME 3, not GNOME 2.

Is there a version of this bridge (or another method) available to get Dogtail to work with QT applications on GNOME 2?

If not, is there a similar tool that would be able to be used to GUI test a QT application without changing the binaries?